# Prometheus DiskTooManyReallocatedSectors

Tags: linux, hard-disk, node.js, smart, prometheus-exporter

I have Prometheus Alert Manager running on several linux machines. *(https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/alertmanager/)*

One of them is reporting *2 reallocated sectors*. I got the setup-alert from here:
*https://awesome-prometheus-alerts.grep.to/rules.html*

**1. What is my course of action?** Replace with an SDD?

**2. What is the priority ...weeks, months?**

[image]

Comment: How often do you see this alert? Same disk, different disks? Have you check in SMART what is the situation?

Comment: -I see this alert as often as the Prometheus-Check is triggered (which is daily).
-Same disk
-Cannot check SMART through my command-line access, cannot install additional software either

Comment: Check this answer in Ubuntu SE: https://askubuntu.com/a/528077/680869 And escalate the case to have at least some tool to check SMART status

Comment: Checked the SMART status: https://i.imgur.com/YuhTudK.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the image of SMART information from this disk I will highly recommend to backup immediate all the information there and replace the disk. You can see the parameter `Reallocated Sector Count` value 100 and the status is **Pre-fail**.

Comment: Answer appreciated. Thank you!